# Facebook AJAX Permissions Dialog NOT in Pop-Up?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, facebook, sdk

I've done some thorough searching and haven't found a direct answer to my question. While there is definitely information about Facebook API AJAX/PHP communication, I can't seem to find an example where the Permission Dialog for an app (showPermissionDialog) is NOT done in a pop-up, but rather in an AJAX-funded div in-page.

The App will be a tab on a facebook page, if that helps your answer.

Is it possible to do this?

Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use the javascript SDK. Specifically the FB.login function.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/

Answer (score 0):

There is no special function or option for a different type of popup. The Javascript SDK decides how the permissions dialog will be displayed. In your your specific use case, if the popup is being invoked as a window, then that is the only way that it can be shown.